# SQL Query to update data from 2 tables into another one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table_a that I want to update with data from 2 other tables.

```
table_a
+----+---------+------------+-------+
| id |  user   |    date    | valid | 
+----+---------+------------+-------+
| 10 | Bob     |            |       |
| 11 | Joe     |            |       |
| 12 | Joe     |            |       |
| 13 | Pete    |            |       |
| 14 | Bob     |            |       | 
+----+---------+------------+-------+
```

the date comes from table_b where table_b.rel_id = table_a.id

```
table_b
+----+----------+----------+
| id |  rel_id  |  date    | 
+----+----------+----------+
| 30 |    8     | 10/10/11 |
| 31 |    9     | 10/10/11 |
| 32 |   10     | 10/10/11 |
| 33 |   11     | 10/10/11 |
| 34 |   12     | 10/10/11 |
| 35 |   13     | 10/10/11 |
| 36 |   14     | 10/10/11 |        
+----+----------+----------+
```

and valid comes from table_c where table_c.rel_id = table_a.id

```
table_c
+----+----------+----------+
| id |  rel_id  |  valid   | 
+----+----------+----------+
| 40 |   10     |   yes    |
| 41 |   11     |   no     |
| 42 |   12     |   yes    |
| 43 |   13     |   no     |
| 44 |   14     |   yes    |
| 45 |   15     |   no     |
| 46 |   16     |   yes    |        
+----+----------+----------+
```

How can this be done with a SQL-Query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply join the tables using `INNER JOIN`.

```
UPDATE  table_a a
        INNER JOIN table_b b
            ON a.id = b.rel_id
        INNER JOIN table_c c
            ON a.id = c.rel_id
SET     a.date = b.date,
        a.valid = c.valid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a2c4/1)

Comment: @mellamokb gee thanks, i was also busy doing fiddle and fixing the typo `:)`

Comment: You guys are amazing, answer in no time and perfectly presented with SQLFiddle. I can't even write that fast. Thanks a lot!